# How to extract list of arrivals correctly using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Good evening, colleagues!

I need help to extract [list of arrivals](https://gearbest.net):

I have the following snippet of the code as below one:
...

```
WebElement newArrivals = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
        ("//*[text()='New Arrivals']")));

List<WebElement> liElements = newArrivals.findElements(By
        .className("like_products_box"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='New Arrivals']")).click();
```

The problem is in debug I'm still getting `zero (0)` as result `(products)`. For this reason, I'm attaching the screen.

Also I have already tried multiple variants with cssSelectors, xpath and so on, but still looking for any valid ideas with it.

```
/*WebElement ulElement = driver
                .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[4]/ul"));
        List<WebElement> liElements = ulElement.findElements(By.tagName("div"));*/

        /*WebElement industries = driver.findElement(
                By.cssSelector("body > div:nth-child(22) > div > div > div > div.like_title.themes_box_title"));*/

        /*WebElement newArrivals = driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                ("//*[text()='New Arrivals']")));*/
```

I hope someone will not ignore my request and help with it or, at least, recommend me what to read.

Thank you in advance for your time on looking it.

*UPD #1*:

```
newArrivals = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'like_title') and contains(@class, 'themes_box_title')]")
```

It works, but I need to extract the whole list of products not one of them specifically.

[image]

*UPD #2*:

```
List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By
                .xpath( "//div[contains(@class, 'like_title') and contains(@class, 'themes_box_title')]"));
```

It works, as well, but it extracts also just one good instead list of them.

[image]

UPD #3:

I need to extract by `like_products_box` instead of `themes_box_title`.

```
...

<div class="products_may_like">
    <div class="wide">
      <div class="like_title themes_box_title">New Arrivals</div>
      <div class="like_products_box">

...
```

UPD #4:

The following snippets return me, as well, `zero(0)`:

1.

```
List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By.
                xpath("div[@class='like_products_box']//div[contains(@class,'like_products_item')]"));
```

2. 

```
List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By.
                xpath( "//div[@class='like_title']//div[@class='like_products_box']"));
```

3. 

```
List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By.
                xpath("a[@class='item_name themes_products_title']"));
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final working solution should be as below:

```
List<WebElement> liElements = driver.findElements(By.
                className("like_products_item"));
```